# How to test Vue component that emits event inside reader.onload()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filereader, vitest

I'm trying to get Vitest to check that an event was emitted when I upload a file. The code works in the real world, but in the testing world, the dummy file I'm passing to the method doesn't get read / doesn't trigger `reader.onload()`.

Here's my component code:

```
export default {

  emits: ["load-file"],

  methods: {
    loadFile(fileList) { 

      if (fileList.length === 1) {

        let file = fileList[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onload = () => {
          let fileJSON = JSON.parse(reader.result);
          this.$emit("load-file", fileJSON);
        };

        reader.onerror = () => {
          console.log(reader.error)
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And here's the test:

```
describe('DropZone Component', () => {

  it('loadFile errors out on non-JSON file', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(DropZone)

    let file = new File(["hello", "world"], "hello_world.txt", {type: "text/plain"});

    wrapper.vm.loadFile([file]);

    expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty("load-file")

  })
```

I'm pretty new to testing Vue, but I couldn't find anything in the docs that would point me in the right direction. If I move the emit to the top of the `loadFile` function, the tests pass, so I must be handling `FileReader` in a way that vitest doesn't expect. I tried adding a pause after calling `wrapper.vm.loadFile([file]);` in the test, but that didn't help, neither did using the `$nextTick`.

What I hope to capture is that the test will fail on `let fileJSON = JSON.parse(reader.result);` line because the dummy file contents isn't valid JSON. And conversely, that if the file did have valid JSON, the `load-file` event would be emitted.